# WPF | What is the name of the resize cursor?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use this kind of controls in my WPF app. I don’t know what they’re called, though.
On the following picture is the cursor which appears when you hover over such a control.
What is the name of this type of control?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its called GridSplitter and you can find another name on youtube example
There are people who call this words

- ResizeMode
- ResizeLayout
- ResizeWindow